# MS Access And VB.net Query Error

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2013

I Have A Table with the following Columns

```
ID(integer)
mat_id(integer)
move_date(Date/Time)
rec_num (Short text)
Qty (number(double))
```

I have made a connection programmatically
and tried a query
the code is as below

```
Public Class ViewMatInfo
    Dim ConStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\RMM\RMMDB.mdb;Persist Security Info=True"
    Dim Conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConStr)
    Dim ShowTable As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim RAD As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            ShowTable.Connection = Conn
            ShowTable.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            ShowTable.CommandText = "SELECT Sum(qty) AS [totqty] FROM moves WHERE [mat_id] = " & MT_TEXT.SelectedValue.ToString & ""
            Conn.Open()
            RAD = ShowTable.ExecuteReader()
            While RAD.Read
                SUM_TEXT.Text = RAD.GetDouble("totqty")
            End While
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
        Try
            Me.MovesTableAdapter.FillByMat(Me.RMMDS.moves, MT_TEXT.SelectedValue)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

When I run the application and select the material from "MT_TEXT" combobox
and then click on the button
the data grid view is filled greatly with all material moves.
but the SUM_TEXT text box is still empty.
and get the error message
"Conversion From string "totqty" to integer is not valid"

Please is there any solution for this problem

Comment: The [documentation for SELECT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821148.aspx) does not show delimiters of any sort around the alias - does it work if you use `SELECT Sum(qty) AS totqty FROM `...? Also, I recommend using SQL parameters instead of concatentating the query value into the SQL string.

Comment: Which line is raising the error? Is it this one? SUM_TEXT.Text = RAD.GetDouble("totqty")

Comment: @Andrew.  Did you fix the code.  Was the answer I gave a fix?

Comment: @Reetal Did you fix the code. Was the answer I gave a fix?

Answer (score 1):

```
  = " & MT_TEXT.SelectedValue.ToString & ""
```

This looks iffy.  Why are there two double quotes at the end and only a single one before.

Should the line read:

```
ShowTable.CommandText 
= "SELECT Sum(qty) AS [totqty] 
FROM moves WHERE [mat_id] = """ & MT_TEXT.SelectedValue.ToString & """"
```